# Element should have been 'select' but was 'ul' - Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am having this issue in my selenium code, while accessing drop down list elements.

Using page object model, below is my page class:

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import Lib.lib;

public class KnowledgeBase extends lib{

    By studiesDD = By.xpath(".//*[@id='warren-nav']/div[3]/ul/li[5]/ul");
    By createBtn = By.id("create-study");

    // Selecting Study Type
    public void selectStudyType(String studyType) throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(createBtn).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Select sType = new Select(driver.findElement(studiesDD));
        sType.selectByVisibleText(studyType);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```

In the above code, 'createBtn' is the button clicking which displays the drop down list and 'studiesDD' is the xpath of the 'ul' that contains the actual data of the list.

Below is the HTML code for the drop down list

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="create-study">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle warren-nav-icon"></i>Create
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu create-dropdown">

        <li data-study-type="event">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.event"
             class="create-study-link event"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" title="event"></i> Event Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="cyclical">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.cyclical"
             class="create-study-link cyclical"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-retweet" title="cyclical"></i> Cyclical Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="conditional">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.conditional"
             class="create-study-link conditional"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-random" title="conditional"></i> Conditional Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="multi_condition">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.multi_condition"
             class="create-study-link multi_condition"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-random" title="multi_condition"></i> Multiple Conditions Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="relative">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.relative"
             class="create-study-link relative"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" title="relative"></i> Relative Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="relative_multiple">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.relative_multiple"
             class="create-study-link relative_multiple"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" title="relative_multiple"></i> Relative Analysis: Multiple Date Ranges
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="regime_change">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.regime_change"
             class="create-study-link regime_change"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-globe" title="regime_change"></i> Global Scenario Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="consensus_analysis">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.consensus_analysis"
             class="create-study-link consensus_analysis"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece" title="consensus_analysis"></i> Economic Consensus/Surprise Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="trigger">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.trigger"
             class="create-study-link trigger"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-random" title="trigger"></i> Trigger Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="earnings_analysis">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.earnings_analysis"
             class="create-study-link earnings_analysis"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" title="earnings_analysis"></i> Earnings Consensus/Surprise Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-study-type="price_movement_analysis">
          <a href="/finance/warren/studies/new/kensho.price_movement_analysis"
             class="create-study-link price_movement_analysis"
             target="_self">
            <i class="fa fa-line-chart" title="price_movement_analysis"></i> Price Movement Trigger Analysis
          </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
```

In the HTML code, `class = "dropdown-toggle"` represents 5 different drop down links and I am trying to access the one with `id = "create-study"`. The xpath for studiesDD button in my page class has the class value as `<ul class="dropdown-menu create-dropdown">`, but I am not using it as it gives error for compound class (due to space between the words).

Now, when I run my test, it gives me the following error,

```
Element should have been "select" but was "ul"
```

If I change the select statement in my page class to following,

```
Select sType = new Select(driver.findElement(createBtn));
```

then I get the following error,

```
Element should have been "select" but was "a"
```

Can somebody help me solving this issue. It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While the dropdown might look like a real HTML `SELECT` tag, it is in fact not and that's why you are getting error messages around should have been "select" but was X. The `Select` class that you are using is for actual HTML `SELECT` tags and can't be used elsewhere.

What you want is the code below. I rewrote the `selectStudyType()` method to take a String parameter that corresponds to the CSS class on the `A` tags that you will want to click to make your function work.

I generally don't like write functions like this because it requires the consumer to have internal knowledge of the HTML page which is, in general, not a best practice. I would instead write a function for each of the study types and give them specific names, e.g. `clickEventAnalysisLink()`. That makes it dumb obvious to the consumer what that method does.

```
/**
 * Selecting Study Type
 * @param studyType
 *            the CSS class name on the A tag that corresponds to the study link. Current types are "event", "cyclical", etc.
 */
public void selectStudyType(String studyType)
{
    driver.findElement(createBtn).click();
    // you might need a slight pause here waiting for the dropdown to load and open
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.create-study-link." + studyType)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a *ul* html element to a *select* type. That means, thefollowing part of your code -

```
Select sType =
```

could be used only if the dropdown has been a `<select>` element. In this particular scenario, you will have to find the element to be clicked using usual `find_element` selenium webdriver functions.

Answer (score -1):

The drop down in html is not usual select element. It is unordered list.

You need to grab the list elements and then iterate through them to get the text you want and select the element. It can be as below code

```
    // Selecting Study Type
    public void selectStudyType(String studyType) throws Exception
    {
    List<WebElement> allOptions = dropDown.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-menu li"));

    java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = allOptions.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        WebElement ele = i.next();
        if (ele.text.equals(studyType) {
            ele.click();
        // do something in else perhaps
        }
    }
 }
```